# shorter jQuery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and still learning. The code I have right now works and it does what I want except it's too long and inefficient I was wondering if there is a way to make it shorter and more dynamic. There are 6 div elements

```
    <header>
      <div id="menubar1" class="menubar one">
        <p class="place"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-apple fa-5x label"></i></p>
        <p id="clasi1" class="clasi">text</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menubar2" class="menubar six">
        <p class="place"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x label"></i></p>
        <p id="clasi2" class="clasi">text</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menubar3" class="menubar three">
        <p class="place"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-pencil fa-5x label"></i></p>
        <p id="clasi3" class="clasi">text</p>
      </div>

    </header>
```

// there are 3 more div elements

and jquery code for each div (and there are 4 more)

```
  $('#menubar1').on("mouseover", function() {
    $('#clasi1').css({
      'paddingTop': '35px',
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $('#clasi1').css({
      'paddingTop': '10px',
      'opacity': 0.6
    });
  });

  $('#menubar2').on("mouseover", function() {
    $('#clasi2').css({
      'paddingTop': '35px',
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $('#clasi2').css({
      'paddingTop': '10px',
      'opacity': 0.6
    });
  });
```

On hover div element with id menubar1, menubar2, etc. I want to add css properties(padding-top and opacity) to p element under that div with class clasi1, clasi2,etc.

Comment: *"if there is a way to make it shorter and more dynamic"* Yup. className selectors.

Comment: Looks like you'd be able to get rid of all of it with a `:hover` selector in CSS.

Comment: I have just added div.menubar:hover p.clasi {} in css, it was to easy but i was blind idk

Answer (score 7):

Shorter javascript?  How does zero sound?

```
.menubar .clasi {
  paddingTop: 10px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.menubar:hover .clasi {
   paddingTop: 35px;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

That said, if you were doing something that couldn't be done in pure CSS, a click handler for example, class selectors instead of individual IDs will be more reusable:

```
$('.menubar').on('click', function() {
  // 'this' is now the .menubar which was moused over. 
  // $(this).find() will return matching nodes inside it:
  $(this).find('.clasi').css({
    // etc
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw it and made the changes in css 5 min ago

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(".menubar")
.on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).find(".clasi").css({
        paddingTop: '35px',
        opacity: 1
    });
})
.on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).find(".clasi").css({
        paddingTop: '10px',
        opacity: 0.6
    });
});
```